# Unable to calculate the summation for -ve numbers

Tags: c++

I have written the following program for finding the no of pairs which produce equal sums. The program is working just fine for the positive numbers but when it comes to the -ve numbers it is showing 0 pairs are there.

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cmath>
// Include headers as needed
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Write your code here
    int t,a,b;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cin>>a>>b;
        int *x,*y,count=0;
        int c[a];
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++) cin>>c[i];

        x=&c[0],y=&c[a-1];

        while(*x!=*y){
            if((*x+*y)==b) {count++; *(x++),*(y--);}
            else if((*x+*y)>b) {*(y--);}
            else if((*x+*y)<b) {*(x++);}
        }
        if(b%2==0)
        cout<<count/2<<endl;
        else cout<<count/2<<endl;
    }
    // Return 0 to indicate normal termination
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the input I am trying with

```
1
10 -99
-100000 -500 -100 -50 -25 -10 -5 0 1 2
```

Output is 0

Comment: why output  `count/2`?

Comment: Some commenting would have been nice. I figured out that the `1` / `t` is the number of loops, `10` / `a` is the count of numbers expected in the third line, and `-99` / `b` is the sum that pairs of numbers from the third line should be checked against. What your inner `while` loop is *supposed* to do, I don't know, because I got bored trying to figure it out.

Comment: `*(x++)` - huh? why the dereferencing? it's unnecessary.

Comment: "The program is working just fine for the positive numbers" - no it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I persevered.

```
    while(*x!=*y){
        if((*x+*y)==b) {count++; *(x++),*(y--);}
        else if((*x+*y)>b) {*(y--);}
        else if((*x+*y)<b) {*(x++);}
    }
```

1. If the left and the right number sum up to `-99`, you increase `count`, and shift left and right pointer "inward" (and dereference them, which is a no-op here).
2. If the sum is larger than `-99`, you shift the right pointer inward (left) (and dereference, see above).
3. If the sum is smaller than `-99`, you shift the left pointer inward (right) (and dereference, see above).

Let's see what happens:

-100000 + 2 = -99998. Case 3, left pointer shifted.

-500 + 2 = -498. Case 3, left pointer shifted.

-100 + 2 = -98. Case 2, right pointer shifted.

-100 + 1 = -99. Case 1, both pointers shifted, `count` is now `1`.

-50 + 0 = -50. Case 2, right pointer shifted.

-50 + -5 = -55. Case 2, right pointer shifted.

-50 + -10 = -60. Case 2, right pointer shifted.

-50 + -25 = -75. Case 2, right pointer shifted.

Pointers are equal, loop ends, `count` is still `1`.

Since both parts of the `if / else` are equal (huh?), you now print `count/2`, which is an integer division, and thus rounded to `0`.

If you *intended* a different thing to happen, I wouldn't know, because you didn't comment your code with your intentions. So all we have is the code, which works as above. (As a couple of debug outputs could have told you).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Bad output?